# How to check if a string is present at the beginning of another string in java

Tags: java, string

I have figured it out how to check if a string is present in another string. But I need to know how can we check if a string is present at the very start of another string.
for example:
String str1="first not";
String str2="not last";
I need a condition to check if "not" is present at the start of the string which should be satisfying only for the case of str2 rather than both.

Comment: Have you tried `String#startsWith`?

Comment: For future reference: In order to do at least a minimal bit of research, you can always look up the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: yes my mistake, removing comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have [`startsWith`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith-java.lang.String-) method in String class.

```
yourString.startsWith("not")
```